# Result show -nan after getting the data from priority_queue

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, structure, allocation

I wrote code to assign the values to struct nngNode,but when I checked the result inside nngNode,the result displays -nan.I don't know why the -nan comes out.Before the result of nngNode,I can see the correct result from array.Here is the code :

1.

```
struct nngNode{

int x;
int y;
int pixelval;
int pixelnum;
double ndist;
nngNode(int x, int y, int pixelVal,int pixelNum,double ndist) : x(x), y(y), pixelval(pixelval),pixelnum(pixelnum),ndist(ndist) {}

};

struct cmp2{

   bool operator()(nngNode &para1, nngNode &para2) {
        return para1.ndist > para2.ndist;
    }

};

template<class T1>
class Array2D{

public:
        int arows=0;
        int acols=0;
        T1**  __restrict matImg;
Array2D(int rows,int cols,T1 defaultVal):arows(rows),acols(cols){

matImg=new T1*[rows];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
   matImg[i]=new T1[cols];
   memset(matImg[i],defaultVal,sizeof(T1)*cols);
   }
}

T1 &operator()(int m, const int n){

 return matImg[m][n];


 }


T1 *operator()(int k){

 return matImg[k];

}


~Array2D(){

for(int i=0;i<arows;i++){
    delete[] matImg[i];
   }
   delete [] matImg;

 }

};


int ragNode=0;
int pixelSum[id]={0};
int pixelNum[id]={0}


(After calculation the pixelSum and pixelNum have numbers.)
priority_queue<nngNode,vector<nngNode>,cmp2>nngprioq;

Array2D<double> neighDist(id,id,0);
//#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:ragNode) 
for(int i=0;i<id;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<id;j++){
    if(idArr(i,j)==1&&pixelNum[i]>0&&pixelNum[j]>0){
    ragNode++;
   // double powerDis=((pixelSum[i]/pixelNum[i]-pixelSum[j]/pixelNum[j])/(rows*cols))*((pixelSum[i]/pixelNum[i]-pixelSum[j]/pixelNum[j])/(ros));oll
    double powerDis=pow((((double)pixelSum[i])/(double)pixelNum[i]-((double)pixelSum[j])/(double)pixelNum[j]),2);
    double mulelement=((double)pixelNum[i])*((double)pixelNum[j]);
    double divelement=(double)(pixelNum[i]+pixelNum[j]);
    cout<<"------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"powerDis:"<<powerDis<<endl;
    cout<<"mulelement:"<<mulelement<<endl;
    cout<<"divelement:"<<divelement<<endl;
    cout<<"("<<i<<","<<j<<")"<<endl;
    cout<<"psum"<<pixelSum[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"pnum"<<pixelNum[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"distance of"<<"("<<i<<","<<j<<"):"<<((mulelement*powerDis)/divelement)<<endl;
    neighDist(i,j)=((mulelement*powerDis)/divelement)+1.0;
    nngNode newnode=nngNode(i,j,pixelSum[i],pixelNum[i],neighDist(i,j));
    nngprioq.push(newnode);

       }
     }
}
```

Here is the result from above :(only part from the whole result)

```
------------------------------------
powerDis:0.681595
mulelement:47124
divelement:1711
(240,255)
psum61
pnum28
distance of(240,255):18.7724
------------------------------------
powerDis:0.425937
mulelement:26376
divelement:970
(240,268)
psum61
pnum28
distance of(240,268):11.582
------------------------------------
powerDis:4.33408
mulelement:295656
divelement:1718
(241,170)
psum1055
pnum194
distance of(241,170):745.865
------------------------------------
powerDis:8.18913
mulelement:285374
divelement:1665
(241,201)
psum1055
pnum194
distance of(241,201):1403.58
------------------------------------
powerDis:1.25224
mulelement:295462
divelement:1717
(241,247)
psum1055
pnum194
distance of(241,247):215.487
------------------------------------
powerDis:0.0334138
mulelement:25050
divelement:551
(242,219)
psum129
pnum50
distance of(242,219):1.51908
------------------------------------
powerDis:1.1664
mulelement:100
divelement:52
(242,233)
psum129
pnum50
distance of(242,233):2.24308
------------------------------------
powerDis:1.84341
mulelement:246
divelement:47
(243,251)
psum122
pnum41
distance of(243,251):9.6485
------------------------------------
powerDis:0.00629865
mulelement:46986
divelement:1187
(243,267)
psum122
pnum41
distance of(243,267):0.249325
------------------------------------
powerDis:0.0911844
mulelement:10521
divelement:522
(244,219)
psum44
pnum21
distance of(244,219):1.83784
------------------------------------
```

2. 

Here is the nngNode ode of priority queue,the weird thing is pixelval coming from pixelSum[i],pixelnum coming from pixelNum[i] are 1,and 0.I don't understand the why the result comes out.Because from above in array,the number of ndist,pixelval and pixelnum can be seen as result.

```
int ncounter=0;

cout<<"---------------------nng queue---------------------------"<<endl;

while(!nngprioq.empty()){
         cout<<"---------------------------------------------"<<endl;
         cout<<ncounter<<"st Element:"<<endl;
         cout<<"distanceValue:"<<(double)nngprioq.top().ndist<<endl;
         cout<<"x:"<<nngprioq.top().x<<endl;
         cout<<"y:"<<nngprioq.top().y<<endl;
         cout<<"sumPixel:"<<nngprioq.top().pixelval<<endl;
         cout<<"numPixel:"<<nngprioq.top().pixelnum<<endl;
         nngprioq.pop();
         ncounter++;
}
```

Here is the result with -nan:

```
x:1
y:6
sumPixel:1
numPixel:0
---------------------------------------------
913st Element:
distanceValue:-nan
x:1
y:0
sumPixel:1
numPixel:0
---------------------------------------------
914st Element:
distanceValue:-nan
x:1
y:4
sumPixel:1
numPixel:0
---------------------------------------------
915st Element:
distanceValue:-nan
x:0
y:26
sumPixel:1
numPixel:0
---------------------------------------------
916st Element:
distanceValue:-nan
x:0
y:11
sumPixel:1
numPixel:0
---------------------------------------------
917st Element:
distanceValue:-nan
x:0
y:20
```

Could someone provide any hint or suggestions?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you,I made a mistake there.I have updated the struct.The -nan did not come any more.However I still have the problem of pixelnum and pixelval,there are still 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who share your time to review my quesion.I have found the issue which are about struct parameter and name of parameter.By changing pixelSum into pixelsum and add ndist(ndist).The issue is solved.